# Why Jvector object behaves differently depending on how it was created?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jvectormap

I am working with Jvector maps. I've got two options to create vector maps using either

```
    $('#visitors-map').vectorMap({
                                map : 'world_merc_en',

                                //container : $('#visitors-map'),

                                hoverOpacity : 0.5,
                                hoverColor : false,
                                markerStyle : {
                                    initial : {
                                        fill : '#4cabc7',
                                        stroke : 'transparent',
                                        r : 3
                                    }
                                },
.....
```

or using new key word that is.

```
map = new jvm.Map({
    map: 'es_merc_en',
    container: $('#visitors-map''),
    series: {
...
```

What is the main difference of these two methods? When I used the second option, I noticed that it renders only first time. I have inserted the map inside a div which can expand and minimize. When I try to expand the map, I noticed that it doesn't redraw.

Comment: @Teemu, if you feel that it's not the same, cast a reopen vote

Comment: @zzzzBov, I checked your link, it is not what I was looking for. In my application, above two options I mentioned, make a huge difference.

Comment: @mankadanka, please update your question (particularly the title) to make this distinction clear. You'll also need to supply a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).